# What does "array must have exactly two members" mean?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress, callback

I am trying to set up a custom walker for my wordpress menu. Its purpose is to allow me to add php code to the menu links as I could with text and images like this:

```
<a href="http://mcadrives.com/?ref=<?PHP code goes here?>">
```

The php coding I have been using on every hyperlink and image is this:

```
<a href="http://mcadrives.com/?ref=
    <?php
       if (!empty ( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])){
         echo substr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],4); }
       else{ 
         echo 'mhammonds'; }
    ?>>
```

I added this to my functions.php file:

```
class Query_Nav extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';

        //ADD YOUR PHP HERE TO DETERMINE WHATEVER IT IS YOU NEED FOR YOUR LINK
        if ( ! empty ( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ) ) {
            $addedStuff = '?ref=' . substr( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 4 );
            }else { 
                    $addedStuff = '?ref=mhammonds';
}
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url.$addedStuff) .'"' : '';
        ////////////////////

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

and I added this walker 'new Query_Nav' to my nav-menu-template.php:

```
function wp_nav_menu( $args = array() ) {
    static $menu_id_slugs = array();

    $defaults = array( 'menu' => '', 'container' => 'div', 'container_class' => '', 'container_id' => '', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'menu_id' => '',
    'echo' => true, 'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu', 'before' => '', 'after' => '', 'link_before' => '', 'link_after' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth' => 0, 'walker' => 'new Query_Nav()', 'theme_location' => '' );
```

I was then informed by a WARNING that class 'new Query_Nav()' is not found on Line 660, so I added it like so:

```
function walk_nav_menu_tree( $items, $depth, $r ) {
    $walker = ( empty($r->walker) ) ? new Walker_Nav_Menu : $r->walker;
    $args = array( $items, $depth, $r );

    return call_user_func_array( array( $walker, 'walk', 'new Query_Nav()'), $args );
```

Now I have another WARNING stating:

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members in /home/ballaboy258/public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line 660
```

I have removed each one and neither has solved the problem. If I remove $walker, then 'walk' is not found. If I remove 'walk', then 'new Query_Nav()' is not found. If I remove 'new Query_Nav()', again, "new Query_Nav()' is not found. It doesn't make any sense. 
Did I miss a step, or is my syntax wrong? I'm confused and I can't find anything on the web to help me.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your callback array

```
array( $walker, 'walk', 'new Query_Nav()'),
```

should comprise two elements

- a class
- a method

that represent the function you are calling

You have provided three

Comment: I have removed each one and neither has solved the problem. If I remove $walker, then 'walk' is not found. If I remove 'walk', then 'new Query_Nav()' is not found. If I remove 'new Query_Nav()', again, "new Query_Nav()' is not found. It doesn't make any sense. @MarkBaker